# Fill textbox with a href link

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to get a textbox filled with a name that has been clicked on, I got it working but for some reason the whole page will lose it's whole layout. All the other included documents end styling sheet are getting excluded for some reason.

Part of my code, which causes the problem, (exchange.php):

```
$selectednaam = '';

if (isset($_GET['q']))
{                                   
    $selectednaam = $_GET['q'];
}

if ($selectednaam != '')
{                                   
    echo("<tr>
        <td>
            <form method='post'><input type='text' name='otheruser' value='$selectednaam' $disabled/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name='amount' value='$amount' $disabled />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='submit' name='exchange' value='Exchange' />
        </td>
    </tr>");
}
else
{
    echo("<tr>
        <td>
            <form method='post'><input type='text' name='otheruser' value='$name' $disabled />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name='amount' value='$amount' $disabled />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='submit' name='exchange' value='Exchange' />
        </td>
    </tr>");
}

if(isset($_POST['list']))
{
    while($fetchusers = mysql_fetch_array($findusers))
    {
        $otherusers = $fetchusers['user'];
        echo("<tr><td><a href='exchange.php?q=$otherusers'>$otherusers</a></td></tr>");
    }
}
```

Is there a quick way to get the textbox filled without losing the whole page styling?

Comment: Are you calling this in an ajax request or just a form submit?

Comment: I can't see why the styling is breaking from the code you provided, but there are two things that may help troubleshoot. First, remove the second if and just include $selectednaam in the echo. Set it to $name instead of empty when it is not specified. That will remove the duplicate code. Next, make sure your form element starts outside of the table, not inside.

Comment: @AvAvt with "this" you mean the provided code?

Comment: @jlemley I've don what you said, but it didn't work.

Comment: @BadAtPHP yes I mean are you calling exchange.php in an ajax request or is it the target of a form? Since you said the rest of the document is excluded I just thought that maybe you were simply calling a GET request to exchange.php. If that's the case of course you would only get the part echo-ed by the php file.

Comment: Please edit the code to include the styling information and more details.

Comment: @AvAvt the first time exchange.php gets called by a case statment, but the second time when you press a name from this line: `<tr><td><a href='exchange.php?q=$otherusers'>$otherusers</a></td></tr>` a GET statement gets called: `if (isset($_GET['q']))`. So I guess you found the problem.